# How does computer draw a line??

Tags: graphics, gdi

Windows GDI has these functions:

MoveTo();

LineTo();

They accept coordinates where to start drawing and where to stop drawing.

But how are these functions implemented?? (especially LineTo)

Do they need to calculate all points between point A and point B??

How is this line drawn exactly??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they calculate each individual point between A and B.

The most common way to do this efficiently is known as [Bresenham's Line Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Note that Windows LineTo does not draw the last point. When line segments are drawn one after another, this prevents the endpoints from being double drawn.

Answer (score 2):

nobody who never saw the Windows source code can answer this in-depth...
BUT Windows is just as any other software: it needs some algorithm to draw a line... one such algorithm you can see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

The Moveto is "easier" in that it just updates the current coordinates the system know of...

Comment: maybe, someone who saw Windows source code is also StackOverflow user.. :)

Comment: possible... but even then I would be pretty sure that there would be an NDA prohibiting to share anything he saw in the source :-)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need to calculate all points between A and B (which are infinite) but only the discrete pixels between A and B. That's usually a standard line rasterization algorithm. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) for Bresenham's line rasterization algorithm, which is the standard school book example and usually the base for more flexible rasterization algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is more going on that just (a form of) Bresenham as there is also (optional) anti-aliasing. see [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm) for what might be the implemented algoritm (Xiaolin Wu's line algorithm)